# ¿Como quitar solicitud de ubicación en segundo plano en react native expo app android según google play console?

Tags: android, react-native, expo, geolocation-api

tengo una app desarrollada en react native y expo. Ya la tengo terminada, la he subido a google play console (fichero .aab) y me está diciendo que no cumple con las políticas de ubicación en segundo plano. Que que si no uso la localización en segundo plano que lo quite.
Mi aplicación no requiere la ubicación para nada y que yo sepa no he puesto nada al respecto.

¿Como le digo en mi Visual Studio Code donde tengo el fuente en React Native que no use eso? ¿En un androidmanifest.xml en el raíz? ¿en package.json?

Gracias y saludos
Enrique

Comment: Hola Juan, recuerda que es importante agregar lo que trataste, recuerda realizar tus preguntas en base a [ask], saludos.

Comment: De acuerdo, mejoraré la forma de preguntar. Saludos.

Answer (score 2):

Pues al final lo he solucionado poniendo lo siguiente en [app.json](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#permissions):

```
"permissions": []
```

Así se solicitan los permisos minimos y google play console ya no avisa de ese error.